why I get two quote characters in my PDF?
I generate pdfs with api2pdf
I see two quote characters before my table

How can I remove this and why it comes ?
code:
    const d = await clientPDF.chromeHtmlToPdf(`
      <h1>Stundenzettel</h1>

      <section>
        <p>Name: james test</p>
        <p>Zeitraum: 3 2024</p>
        <p>Gesamtstunden: 80</p>
      </section>

      <table id="customers">
        <tr>
          <th>Datum</th>
          <th>Auftrag</th>
          <th>Beginn</th>
          <th>Ende</th>
          <th>Pause</th>
          <th>Gesamt</th>
        </tr>
          ${ calculateAllPauseTimesArrayToMinutes.map((el => (
            `
            <tr>
            <td>${format(el.start_time, 'PP', {  locale: de } )}</td>
            <td class="text-ellips">${el.location_name ?? '/'}</td>
            <td>${format(el.start_time, 'p', {  locale: de } )}</td>
            <td>${format(el.end_time, 'p', {  locale: de } )}</td>
            <td>${el.pause_times.length > 0 ? el.pause_times.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) : '/'}</td>
            <td>${parseFloat((differenceInMinutes(el.end_time, el.start_time) / 60).toFixed(2))}</td></tr>`
          )))
          }
      </table>
      `, { options: options });

I removed the spaces in my tr td where I map it but it also not going away. Idk why it comes I hope anyone can give me the answer where the problem is
€: when I remove map it goes away so it has to do with the map function

Those are not quote characters, they are commas. map returns an array, and when you force an array into a string context, that will cause an implicit join of the array elements, with a comma a separator between them.
So you are effectively creating HTML of the form <tr>...</tr>,<tr>...</tr>,<tr>...</tr> here. But because non-whitespace characters between table rows are not allowed, the browser moves them above the table when parsing this whole construct, as easily evidenced by this tiny example:


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>,
  <tr>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>,
  <tr>
    <td>baz</td>
  </tr>
</table>



To get these array elements joined with "nothing" in between them, you need to explicitly invoke the join method with an empty string as the separator character.
${ calculateAllPauseTimesArrayToMinutes.map(...).join('') }

